# 7. Reverse Integer cannot get it to work using Python. exceeds time integer bound?

Tags: python, algorithm

Reverse digits of an integer.

Example1: x = 123, return 321
Example2: x = -123, return -321

Note:
The input is assumed to be a 32-bit signed integer. Your function should return 0 when the reversed integer overflows.

```
class Solution(object):
    def reverse(self, x):
        """
        :type x: int
        :rtype: int
        """
        ret=0
        while x!=0:
            ret=ret*10+x%10
            x=x/10
            if ret<=-2147483648 or ret >= 2147483647:
                return 0
        return ret
```

Comment: Which Python version is this? In Python 3, you'd better use `//` instead of `/`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the working code for it,

```
class Solution(object):
    def reverse(self, x):
        """
        :type x: int
        :rtype: int
        """
        ret=0
        neg_flag = False
        if x<0:
            neg_flag = True
            x = x*(-1)
        while x!=0:
            ret=ret*10+x%10
            x=x/10
            if ret<=-2147483648 or ret >= 2147483647:
                return 0
        if neg_flag:
            ret = ret * -1
        return ret
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: I don't understand why -321%10 does not equal to -1??

Comment: % is used for modulus, so when you divide it by 10 what is the remainder left that is returned by the % sign.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more elegant solution that should work for you:

```
    def reverse(self, x):
        """
        :type x: int
        :rtype: int
        """
        temp = int(str(abs(x))[::-1])
        if temp > 2147483647 or temp < -2147483648 :
            return 0
        if (x > 0):
            return temp
        else:
            return -temp
```

Answer (score 0):

Just convert it to a string, then back to an int.  That might be cheating, since it looks like you're doing an assignment.

```
class Solution(object):
    def reverse(self, x):
        """
        :type x: int
        :rtype: int
        """
        y = str(x)
        if y[0] = "-":
            ret = int("-" + y[1:][::-1])
        else:
            ret = int(y[::-1])
        if ret<=-2147483648 or ret >= 2147483647:
            return 0
        return ret
```

Comment: thank you for ur solution. but I think using cutting operation in python would result in more time use